# Final year university project, need a professional sound designer's feedback!

Tags: film-sound-design, sound-design

I'm currently studying digital media in Edinburgh and specialising in film sound.

For my final year project I had to source a film which I could create the sound design for and write a dissertation on relation to its genre and sound design principles.

One aspect of the project requires me to show the piece film to a professional sound designer and interview them for feedback on the films sound.

I was hoping that someone would be free at some point during the last week of March to take part in an interview via Skype to get some feedback on my project. The film itself is a 16 minute section of a horror film shot in Scotland.  The interview itself will last an hour, with the first section consisting of watching the film itself, then using the rest of that time to discuss the sound design.

Below is a link to a section of the film Tron Legacy I created the sound design for, so that you can see that I hopefully have at least some potential!

http://vimeo.com/32876845

I look forward to any responses!

Comment: Nice work, I'm sorry but I laughed when he said "ClUuuuuu"